# php - implement curl command line to php, tried but getting error 

Tags: php, curl

Can anyone convert this curl command that works in command line to php code :

```
$ curl -u username@gmail.com -X POST -d "" https://build.phonegap.com/token
```

I tried this code but didnt work :

```
$target_url = "https://USERNAME@gmail.com:PASSWORD@build.phonegap.com/token"
 $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);

$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

When I am executing the above code , I am getting the error :

```
 301 Moved
 The document has moved here(link to gmail.com).
```

But, if i use the command in command line, it is working fine . Where am i wrong  ?

Also, please tell me what does that "-X" mean, and how can convert it to php code ?

Thanks

Comment: Could be wrong, but shouldn't the @ in the email be url encoded or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`301` is a redirect response code. Add this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
```

...after `curl_init()` and before `curl_exec()` to have cURL follow the redirect to the correct location.

The [`-X`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-X) option is used to specify the `POST` method in your original command string, which you have mirrored with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

**EDIT**

Try this code:

```
$username = "USERNAME@gmail.com";
$password = "PASSWORD";
$target_url = "https://build.phonegap.com/token"

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: ok, but it is redirecting, but it shouldnot redirect, it should return the response as i have given the username and password . The curl command is returning response directly, but why this php code redirecting to gmail.com ?

Comment: Maybe it is expecting a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which I think is what the command line will send but libcurl may not unless you specify some data. See edit above.

Comment: superb, working . can u  plz tel me how u r able to say that they are expecting  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded  this one ???

Comment: Just from reading the [cURL command line docs](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) for the `-d` option. Although in retrospect, I think that it was actually @AlexLunis' suggestion that fixed it, I just implemented that out of habit (by using the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option). The `@` in the username specified in the URL was being interpreted as the break between the username and the domain so you ended up being sent to Gmail. Annoyingly there is no document that explains how command line options relate to libcurl options (AFAIK), you just sort of pick it up as you go along.

Comment: Your best bet would be to read through all the options [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) thoroughly, and if you can't work something out feel free to create a question on SO about it.